# Conditional task if a variable is set

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I have a playbook with the interpreter (ansible_python_interpreter) set manually.

Then I have 2 tasks (foo, bar) as an example.

I only want bar executed if the interpreter is set to python2. How can I make that happen?

```
hosts: "{{ ansible_limit | default (omit) }}"
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: "/usr/bin/python3"
  tasks:
  - name: foo
    shell: /home/test/foo
  - name: bar
    shell: /home/test/bar
```

I tried **when** but did not get the access to the variable right I think.

```
when: ansible_python_interpreter.find('python2') != -1
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and be more specific? `I only want bar executed if the interpreter is set to python2` <= Can the env be setup (discovered) automatically on some hosts (without you defining the `ansible_python_interpreter` variable)? - `I tried when but did not get the access to the variable right I think` <= what is the error or unexpected behavior you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [setup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html) module provides you with the option to [gather](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html#parameter-gather_subset) *python_version*

```yaml
    - setup:
        gather_subset: python_version
    - debug:
        var: ansible_python_version
```

gives for example,

```yaml
  ansible_python_version: 3.8.18
```

Then, test the [version](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#comparing-versions). For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: foo
      when: ansible_python_version is version('3.8', '>')
    - debug:
        msg: bar
      when: ansible_python_version is version('3.8', '<')
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: foo
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/local/bin/python3.8

  tasks:

    - setup:
        gather_subset: python_version

    - debug:
        var: ansible_python_version

    - debug:
        msg: foo
      when: ansible_python_version is version('3.8', '>')

    - debug:
        msg: bar
      when: ansible_python_version is version('3.8', '<')
```